# converting opus media file to webm format

Tags: mp3, webm, opus

I am trying to get the encryption media API to work for my opus audio file, but i cant seem to figure out how to convert my opus audio file to webm file format

Comment: Generally speaking, `ffmpeg -i some-audio-file -acodec copy -f webm output.webm`, but I'm not sure of the encryption part.

Comment: yes that convert my audio file to webm format bht still cant encrypt them at all or even if i encrypted them i couldn't generate manifest for them

Comment: Alright, well show us what you did...

Comment: I fist used this command to convert mp3 to opus    ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -c:a libopus -b:a 320k -vn -f webm -dash 1 audio.opus  then i used this command to connvert opus to webm   ffmpeg -i audio.opus -c:a libopus -b:a 320k -vn -f webm -dash 1 audio_320k.webm   then used this command to encrypt webm file  webme -i audio_320k.webm -o audio_320k_enc.webm -k keyfile.key  then when i try to generate web_dash_manifest manifest file it give me error invalid data

Comment: You can edit your question, so you can show the full command, and the full output of the command where you generate the manifest and get the error.